# Sortable elements move up when I select one for dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsf, jsf-2, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery `sortable` to sort a number of `p:panel`s. However when I select any element to move, the other elements move one place up which makes the positioning difficult. I want to sort exactly as in [jQueryUI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/), where the elements move up only when they overlap. Is there any attribute using which I can do it?

Here's my jsf code:

```
<p:outputPanel id="dragPanel" styleClass="enumDiv">
    <ui:repeat value="#{numberEnumComponent.values}" var="numEnum"
        varStatus="values">
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="td-top,td-top,td-top"
            width="30%" style="padding-left: 10px;">

            <p:panel>
                <p:inputText value="#{numberEnumComponent.values[values.index]}"
                    id="numInput" binding="#{numInput}">
                    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.BigDecimal"></f:converter>
                </p:inputText>
                <h:graphicImage value="#{msg.icon_type_NUMBER_ENUM}" id="enumIcon" style="padding-left:10px;"></h:graphicImage>

                <h:form id="removeForm" style="display:inline-block; padding-left:10px;">
                    <h:commandButton action="#{numberEnumComponent.removeNumEnum}"
                        image="#{numberEnumComponent.values.size() == 1 ? msg.icon_remove_disabled : msg.icon_remove}"
                        immediate="true"
                        disabled="#{numberEnumComponent.values.size() == 1}">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener
                            target="#{numberEnumComponent.removePosition}"
                            value="#{values.index}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
                    </h:commandButton>

                    <p:remoteCommand name="enumMovement" action="#{numberEnumComponent.columnMovement}">
                    </p:remoteCommand>
                </h:form>
            </p:panel>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would probably help to use the [drop placeholder](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#placeholder) to prevent the other elements from moving.  Just style it the same as the other elements:

```
$("#container").sortable({placeholder: '.placeholder'});
```

Comment: Tried it, not working! I am not getting a placeholder at all.

Comment: @Rajath by tried it did you copy and paste what I did without checking your work at all?  Or did you make sure that an element with the `.placeholder` class and `#container` IDs actually make sense in your context?

Comment: I did make sure there was a `.placeholder` element whose style I specified using the `<style>` tag.

Comment: @Rajath take a look at the `sortable` documentation and try using whatever placeholder they suggest

Comment: Working! I had to remove `<h:panelGrid>`.